# UPDATE where have duplicated colums

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know how to update values ​​of a column where they are repeated.

Example I have this

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | Repeated? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NAMEA | 111 | 1234 | No |
| NAMEC | 222 | 5678 | No |
| NAMEB | 222 | 5678 | No |

And I need change column (Repeated?) to YES **WHERE ColumnB and ColumnC are equals** like this:

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | Repeated? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NAMEA | 111 | 1234 | No |
| NAMEC | 222 | 5678 | *Yes* |
| NAMEB | 222 | 5678 | *Yes* |

I tried

```
UPDATE [MY_TABLE]
    SET [Repeated?] = 'Yes'
FROM [MY_TABLE] as A
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ColumnA, ColumnC
    FROM [MY_TABLE]
    GROUP BY ColumnA, ColumnC
) as B
ON B.ColumnC = A.ColumnC, B.ColumnA = B.ColumnA
```

but this didn't work. Can someone assist please?

Comment: by default they come as No, but I need to change it to Yes if the data in column B and C are repeated, I tried a query but I couldn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is actually better than the one you accepted (once you correct the mistakes). Because an `INNER JOIN` means you don't update any rows other than those which need to change to 'Yes' whereas the answer your accepted updates **ALL** rows in the table un-necessarily. The issues you have are

- You combine join conditions using `AND` not `,`.
- Your second join condition is comparing the same column with itself.
- Your second join condition should be ColumnB not ColumnA
- You don't need a sub-query to join a table back on itself.
- But most importantly you didn't add a condition to prevent a row from joining to itself.

```
UPDATE A
    SET [Repeated?] = 'Yes'
FROM [MY_TABLE] AS A
INNER JOIN [MY_TABLE] AS B
ON B.ColumnC = A.ColumnC
    AND B.ColumnB = A.ColumnB
    -- The next condition prevents a row matching itself
    AND B.ColumnA <> A.ColumnA;
```

Notes:

1. When updating a table using `FROM` you `UPDATE` the alias not the table name.
2. Best practice is not to name columns using characters that require you to escape them e.g. `[Repeated?]` just use `Repeated` (or I would use `IsRepeated`).
3. You are better off querying this when you need it, rather than having to update the table every time it changes.

Comment: @Bauns On retrospect I think  Dales answer is correct one.  It's the Queens Jubilee, so I've had a bit of wine so maybe I shouldn't have answered in the first place.  I'm not sure if you can you revoke the green tick and give it to Dale instead?

Comment: You're accidently joining on column A,C rather than B,C

Comment: Thanks guys! 
I actually saw the error later, this would be the best approach, as the other one did not consider column B

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick

```
UPDATE yt1
    SET Repeated= (CASE WHEN yt2.ColumnA IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END)
FROM YourTable yt1
LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTable yt2
    ON yt1.ColumnB = yt2.ColumnB AND yt1.ColumnC = yt2.ColumnC
WHERE yt1.ColumnA <> yt2.ColumnA
```

Comment: And a good answer contains an explanation in addition to (hopefully) working code.